# How to structure sass code better when on hover on changes children element status?

Tags: css, sass, hover

I have the following code which on hover of the box element, its background color and child elements text color also change. As you can see after the `&:hover` I'm repeating my `box-title` and `box-subtitle` structure, how can I better structure the sass code?

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  
  &-title {
    color: red;
  }
  
  &-subtitle {
    color: green;
  }
  
  &:hover {
    background-color: black;
    & .box {
      &-title {
        color: white;
      }
      &-subtitle {
        color: grey;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-title">This is the title.</div>
  <div class="box-subtitle">This is the subtitle.</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fh3sbn9p/

Comment: You could create a variable `$root : '.box';` and then use it. But I'm not sure that it's what you are looking for. Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/njvfdymo/ . You won't repeat your classes, but you'll repeat the `&:hover` part

Comment: @AmauryHanser thank you, I think maybe this isn't possible to simplify any further.

Answer (score 0):

```
.box-title {
  color: red;
}

.box-subtitle {
  color: green;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;

  &:hover {
    .box-title {
      color: white;
    }

    .box-subtitle {
      color: grey;
    }
  }
}
```